# Not able to save changes in DOM

Tags: javascript, selenium, dom, webdriver

I am trying to provide value for a text field using javascript in Selenium webdriver, I am able to see the changes in DOM but when I refresh or navigate back to page then changes are not shown in DOM.
I think I have to save the DOM after updating but don't know how to do.
Can anyone help me out here ?

Comment: Refresh/navigate will refresh whole page - not sure why do you expect your changes made on one page to somehow persist and appear on some other page. There is probably more to your problem than present in the post but without small, but reasonably complete sample it is hard to suggest anything.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.